# Unset key "C-;" in Aquamacs, bound to toggle-mac-option-modifier

Tags: key-bindings, aquamacs

I use Aquamacs. `C-;` is bound to `toggle-mac-option-modifier`. When I use C-h k C-;, I get

> ^; runs the command toggle-mac-option-modifier, which is an
>   interactive Lisp function in `emulate-mac-keyboard-mode.el'.

I want to remove this keybinding so I can use elsewhere. I have tried

```
(global-unset-key (kbd "C-;"))
(define-key toggle-mac-option-modifier [C-\;] nil)
(define-key emulate-mac-keyboard-mode [C-\;] nil)
(define-key emulate-mac-keyboard-mode [?\C-\;] nil)
(define-key emulate-mac-keyboard-mode [C-\;] nil)
(define-key emulate-mac-keyboard-mode [control-\;] nil)
(define-key emulate-mac-keyboard-mode-map [control-\;] nil)
(define-key emulate-mac-keyboard-mode [control \;] nil)
(define-key emulate-mac-keyboard-mode (kbd "C-;") nil)
(define-key toggle-mac-keyboard-modifier (kbd "C-;") nil)
(define-key toggle-mac-option-modifier "C-;" nil)
```

I keep getting the error that the

> symbol's value as variable is void

After much searching I found somewhere that maybe the value of the variable had not been initialised, so I tried those after

```
(require 'emulate-mac-keyboard-mode)
```

with the same result. I also tried

```
(eval-after-load 'emulate-mac-keyboard-mode
  '(progn
     (define-key emulate-mac-keyboard-mode [C-\;] nil)))
```

How can I unset this key?

Comment: +1 for showing your work. ;)  Clarifying question: does "I want to remove this keybinding so I can use elsewhere" mean you want to bind `toggle-mac-option-modifier` to a different key, or you want to use `C-;` for a different command?  If the former, it's not a problem to have the same command bound to multiple keys -- no need to unbind.  If the latter, you can just set the binding to a new command without unbinding it first.

Comment: In the 30 minutes I spent trying to figure this out, I was thinking of you, @Dan. Every time I try to do something simple in Emacs, I waste hours. Emacs for me is a means to an end, I don't always have the time it requires and often I just learn to live with things the way they are :(

Comment: I wanted to bind commenting in and out everywhere to C-; . That seems quite hard though as it seems like the name of the function is different in every mode. In latex it is comment-or-uncomment-region, bound to C-c ; , in lisp it is paredit-comment-dwim bound to M-; , in matlab it is matlab-comment-region bound to C-c ; . When I try to use (global-set-key (kbd "C-;") comment-dwim) it says that "symbol's value as a variable is void: comment-dwim. I think I will live with the keybindings as they are.

Comment: I think I see the problem:  try `#'comment-dwim` instead.

Comment: @Dan That said, I still don't like C-; bound to toggle-mac-keyboard-modifier. I often press it by mistake and I want to remove that keybinding. How can I do that (ie, what I asked in the question)?

Comment: Warning, key already bound to toggle-mac-option-modifier by minor modes (osx-key-mode), use define-key instead. So I tried a few things until I did (define-key global-map (kbd "C-;") 'comment-dwim) (with and without the #before the ')  and I get no errors, but C-; still gives me toggle-mac-option-modifier.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've switched to the railwaycat/homebrew-emacsmacport so I can't test this easily but I used to do this on Aquamacs:

```
(define-key osx-key-mode-map (kbd "C-;") nil) ; was toggle-mac-option-modifier
```

Comment: Oh, my king! Thank you, that solved the problem :)